# Getting all embed/object elements, including those inside iframes (js/python)

Tags: javascript, python, html, getelementsbytagname

Trying to find all instances of flash objects on a given page, including those inside iframe elements.

Is there a way in javascript that'll account for those found inside iframes besides just

```
document.getElementsByTagName("embed")
document.getElementsByTagName("objects")
```

I'm also working with python and can grab the full source of a page, could that provide an avenue for this to work?

Comment: are the iframes on the same domain ?

Comment: jQuery will make your job easier. Eg usage: `$("embed")` will get all embed elements on your page.

Comment: Negative. The iframes might lead to god-knows-where.

Comment: Also, will using jQuery to get all elements with that tag get me the ones inside the frames?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your goals, it would probably be easiest with jQuery, as Sibi suggests. However, if you have access to Python, you could use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). This would be especially useful if you wish to get data behind those links in any way.

If that is the route you wish to pursue, you could do something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source)

objects = []
objects.extend(soup.find_all('object'))
objects.extend(soup.find_all('embed'))
```

And if that misses the objects inside iframes you could add:

```
iframes = soup.find_all('iframe')
for iframe in iframes:
    objects.extend(iframe.find_all('object'))
    objects.extend(iframe.find_all('embed'))
```